# Why isn't there a `isIn` trait in D?

Tags: d

I am new to D, so I might get something completely wrong, please enlighten me!

As far as I understand from the [documentation](http://dlang.org/traits.html) D offers traits for finding out about function parameter adornments:

```
void fooref(ref int x) { 
  static assert(__traits(isRef, x)); 
  static assert(!__traits(isOut, x)); 
  static assert(!__traits(isLazy, x)); 
} 
void fooout(out int x) { 
  static assert(!__traits(isRef, x)); 
  static assert(__traits(isOut, x)); 
  static assert(!__traits(isLazy, x)); 
} 
void foolazy(lazy int x) { 
  static assert(!__traits(isRef, x)); 
  static assert(!__traits(isOut, x));
  static assert(__traits(isLazy, x));
}
```

*Why isn't there a trait for finding out about the `in` adornment?*

Comment: Probably becase in is the default?

Comment: mmmhhh... does that mean that `in` is sort of redundant? In the sense that `void foo(in intx)` is exactly equivalent to `void foo(int x)`?

Comment: It is not the default and is the same as scope const.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`__traits` and [`std.traits`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits.html) have lots of good stuff in them, but they're not necessarily complete. So, if you find something that you really think should be inspectable with `__traits` or `std.traits`, then please [create an enhancement request](http://d.puremagic.com/issues).

Now, that being said, it wouldn't really make sense for there to be a way to check for `in`. `in` is the same as `const scope` and if you *could* check for `in`, then `const scope` would have to match it as well. Really, do you care about `const` or do you care about `scope`? Or do you care about both? Check for those, not for `in`.

However, unfortunately, at the moment, it doesn't actually work to check for `scope` when `in` was used. [`std.traits.ParameterStorageClassTuple`](http://dlang.org/phobos/std_traits.html#ParameterStorageClassTuple) can be used to get the storage class of a parameter (none, `scope`, `out`, `ref`, and/or `lazy`), but it currently fails to give `scope` for `in`. So, for the moment, you're out of luck. The [bug](http://d.puremagic.com/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=8695) has been reported though.

But you can still check for `const` by doing something like `is(T == const)` (where `T` is the type of the parameter that you're checking).

Comment: I wasn't aware of `std.traits`. Is there a reason for having it additionally to `__traits`?

Comment: `__traits` is what the compiler gives you. `std.traits` is extra stuff built on top of that in the library. In general, I believe that stuff only goes in `__traits_` if it needs to be there rather than being able to be done in the library, but std.traits is much newer, so that may not be entirely true. Some folks have proposed that they be merged in some manner, but there's not currently any sign of that ever happening. At this point, you just use whichever one provides what you need.